# Multi column Listview populated data wont display

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help on a thing, ive been populating a listview via background worker but it appears it had a row count at the end of the loop but the data for is not showing visually on the listview. i really dont know what is happening.
After the background worker process is done. ive put a message box to show the listview item count but it shows no data on listview. Please see picture.
Thank you

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            DataTable dtdt = new DataTable();
            dtdt = qr.history(); // query in sql to datatable

            for (int i = 0; i < dtdt.Rows.Count; i++)// loop data to listviewitem
            {

                DataRow dr = dtdt.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new   ListViewItem(dr["custnum"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["custname"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ratecable"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["rateinternet"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["rateext"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["status"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["classname"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SVCstadd"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SVCctadd"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["svctelno"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bilstadd"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bilctadd"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billtel"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billtel2"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fax"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["zoneno"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["zoneName"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bookno"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["seqno"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Balance"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance1"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance2"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance3"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billamnt"].ToString().Trim());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["maxdate"].ToString().Trim());



                 this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { additemtoLV(listitem); }));


            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        }


 private delegate void additemtoLVdelegat(ListViewItem ls);

    public void additemtoLV(ListViewItem ls)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new additemtoLVdelegat(additemtoLV), ls);
        }
        else
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(ls);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This could be because you are accessing the ListView control from a background thread, whereas it should only accessed from the GUI thread.  Try using View.Invoke to execute the GUI code on the View thread.  Also check in the debugger that the query result values are not all empty, and consider adding an exception handler.

Comment: ive tried to add this code on invoking still not working. I think im missing something. Ive updated the code. can you take a look on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to comments posted please try the below, which should correctly use the GUI thread, and also has basic exception handling in case an unhandled exception is causing the problem :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        DataTable dtdt = new DataTable();
        dtdt = qr.history(); // query in sql to datatable
        var listItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dtdt.Rows.Count; i++)// loop data to listviewitem
        {
            DataRow dr = dtdt.Rows[i];
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["custnum"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["custname"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ratecable"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["rateinternet"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["rateext"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["status"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["classname"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SVCstadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SVCctadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["svctelno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bilstadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bilctadd"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billtel"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billtel2"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fax"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["zoneno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["zoneName"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["bookno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["seqno"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Balance"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance1"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance2"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["balance3"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["billamnt"].ToString().Trim());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["maxdate"].ToString().Trim());

            listItems.Add(listitem);
        }

        this.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => { listView1.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray()); })));
    }
    catch (System.Exception exc)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => { MessageBox.Show("BackgroundWorker error: " + exc);})));
    }
}
```